# silverlight 3 and System.Core.dll version

Tags: .net, silverlight, silverlight-3.0, version

I have a Visual Studio 2008 solution with several projects.  One project is a web site with a Target Framework of ".NET Framework 3.5".  One is a Silverlight 3 Application which was created with the selection (in the dropdown) of ".NET Framework 3.5".

I notice that if I wish to add a reference to System.Core.dll to the website, I am presented (on the .NET tab) with a single choice of version 3.5.0.0, which seems perfectly reasonable to me.

If, however, I drop and re-add a reference to System.Core within the Silverlight application, I am only presented with System.Core version 2.0.5.0.  What's the story here?  I'd very much like to use some of the methods of TimeZoneInfo that [I infer] are only available in .NET 3.5 sp1.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TimeZoneInfo isn't available to Silverlight - you need to use the 2.0.5.0 .NET assembly version (Silverlight).

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that Jeff Wilcox is correct; it was a bit of surprise to find that I haven't been using 3.5 sp1 all along.

I'm just going to work with the TimeZoneInfo class in the in the page code-behind and pass in the results as initParams.